# How can I use Fuel UX pillbox as an element in a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fuelux

I am playing with Fuel UX pillbox component and I want to make it part of a form I have to submit. Unfortunately, the control does not contain any form element to submit which makes it cool but useless (for me). I added a Input::Hidden element in the HTML code but now I have to force the pillbox component to work with the form element which I am not sure how to do.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{name}" class="col-sm-4 control-label text-right">Tags</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <div class="pillbox" data-initialize="pillbox" id="pillbox-{name}">
      <ul class="clearfix pill-group">
        <li class="pillbox-input-wrap btn-group">
          <a class="pillbox-more">and <span class="pillbox-more-count"></span> more...</a>
          <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle pillbox-add-item" placeholder="add item">
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle sr-only">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="suggest dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-toggle="dropdown" data-flip="auto"></ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <input type="hidden" name="{name}" id="{name}" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I really need is to use JavaScript to update the Input::Hidden element when a new tag is added or removed from the list.

Oh, JavaScript is not my forte.

The Fuel UX component has event for **add** and **remove** new tag the probably has to be used but as I mentioned - not sure how to implement it.

If you have any suggestions, please help, or if you have any other suggestions on how to implement the Pillbox component with a HTML form - I am opened to new ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Pillbox events](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#pillbox-usage-events) to capture the pillbox data via the [items method](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#pillbox-usage-methods-items).

HTML:

```
<div class="pillbox" id="myPillbox1">
  <ul class="clearfix pill-group">
    <li class="pillbox-input-wrap btn-group">
      <a class="pillbox-more">and <span class="pillbox-more-count"></span> more...</a>
      <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle pillbox-add-item" placeholder="add item">
      <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle sr-only">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="suggest dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-toggle="dropdown" data-flip="auto"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input id="pillboxInput" type="text" value="">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myPillbox1').on('added.fu.pillbox edited.fu.pillbox removed.fu.pillbox', function pillboxChanged() {
    $('#pillboxInput').val( JSON.stringify( $('#myPillbox1').pillbox('items') )  );
});
```

This example outputs into a JSON object structure, since the pillbox control supports text and value attributes (and more with data attributes) for each pill.

Comment: Nice...I can handle it from here. Thanks